# How to prevent Gnome desktop from crashing?

Tags: gnome

I have ubuntu 10.10 32bit running on my Asus EEEPC 1005PX. I am experiencing frequent desktop crashes. When I turn on my netbook at least once in 5 times the defualt ubuntu theme disapears and the classic gnome theme appears. Many times while doing some work, the desktop crashes and the CLI gets shown, and after a few seconds the login screen appers. I am not using any widgets or dock bars, I just have a single gnome panel with default menus. The crashes also happen when using the default bundled ubuntu apps.  Is there any way to avoid these crashes?

Comment: Do you get an error message from Gnomes crashreporter? Can you put the contents of /var/log/messages and /var/log/kern.log on http://paste.ubuntu.com/? Hardware failures like bad RAM can also cause crashes. Boot to "Memory test" and leave it running for a few hours.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, then please flag explaining that (as well as editing your question with any details you have).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm having the same problem but not very frequently at all, try opening another window(`CTRL+ALT+F6`) and `startx` from there, if the process is already active and you can't have it running twice try to kill it, looking for the process number with `ps aux`, then `kill proc_number`.
I'm not sure if `ps aux` gives the processes started in another session.

Comment: `ps aux | grep 'searchTermHere'` will let you search for it. `ps aux` also gives all of the process.